# Comparing arrays, why is my != if statement being run?

Tags: c

I'm trying to compare two equal arrays, using a for loop and an if statement to see if the values aren't equal. They shouldn't be, but it's running my code after the if anyway.

```
#include <stdio.h>
bool arrayChecker(int a[10], int b[10]);
    int main ()
    {
        bool output;
        int a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        int b[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        output = arrayChecker(&a[10], &b[10]);
        printf("%d", output);
        return 0;
    }
    bool arrayChecker(int a[10], int b[10]){
        bool result = true;
        for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
            if(a[i] != b[i]){
                result = false; 
                printf("this is being printed and shouldn't be'\n");
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: `output = arrayChecker(&a[10], &b[10]);` -> `output = arrayChecker(a, b);`

Comment: With the function call `arrayChecker(&a[10], &b[10]);`, you are passing the address of the (non-existant) 11th element of the arrays `a` and `b`.  However, that function expects the address of the first element of both arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the wrong thing to the arrayChecker function.

You should have:

```
output = arrayChecker(&a[0], &b[0]);
```

or

```
output = arrayChecker(a, b);
```

What you are passing is the address of the memory location right after the end of the arrays, and comparing the 10 ints after that, which hold random values as far as your program is concerned.

Comment: If it solves your problem, you can let us know by accepting the answer, which you do by clicking the checkmark symbol under the down arrow.

Answer (score 0):

1st change: means that the `arrayChecker` gets two pointers to some memory segment (in this case your arrays).

2nd change can be written also as `output = arrayChecker(&a[0], &b[0]);` because with using `&a[0]` you send to your function a reference to the first element of your array. array elements are arranged sequentially one after other in the memory so there is no problem to iterate from the first one (`a[0]`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
bool arrayChecker(int *a, int *b); //first change here
    int main ()
    {
        bool output;
        int a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        int b[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        output = arrayChecker(a, b); //second change here
        printf("%d", output);
        return 0;
    }
    bool arrayChecker(int *a, int *b) {
        bool result = true;
        for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
            if(a[i] != b[i]){
                result = false; 
                printf("this is being printed and shouldn't be'\n");
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: The first change has no effect. Both work the same. It is just a matter of personal preference which syntax to use.

Comment: for me it's a clearer way to read it, as simple as that. it's up to your choice. because maybe for some reason he changes the size of his arrays, so he have to update his function declaration too (which means a possible bug if he forget to do it, simple bug but still a bug).

Comment: I agree that your syntax is clearer, and I prefer it myself. However, your answer does not explain this. Rather, your answer is implying that OP's answer is not using pointers, whereas your "first change" does cause pointers to be used.

Comment: Small correction -- if you change the function signature in the prototype / declaration, you have to change it in the implementation/ definition as well.